# Understanding the binary xls file-format

Tags: excel, binaryfiles

I'm trying to read the contents of a xls-file without the use of any xls-libraries but having problems doing so.

I'm trying to use information I found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615597.aspx). It has a little step-by-step instruction of how to read the file.
Also using this [xls-file-specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/E/0BE8BDD7-E5E8-422A-ABFD-4342ED7AD886/Excel97-2007BinaryFileFormat%28xls%29Specification.pdf).

I'm not sure if I even do this step correctly:

> 3, Open the Workbook stream and scan for the first instance of a BOF record. This is the beginning of the Globals substream.

According to the file-specification or this page with a [list of the record-numbers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd908813%28v=office.12%29.aspx), I should be looking for for 2057(0809h) but the whole file doesn't contain that record anywhere(also using a hexa-editor when trying to find it).
But then I read this part on page 20 in the specification:

> Byte Swapping Excel BIFF files are transportable across the
>   MS-DOS/Windows and Apple Macintosh operating systems, among others. To
>   support transportability, Excel writes BIFF files where the low-order
>   byte of the word appears first in the file, followed by the highorder
>   byte.

If I understand that correctly (not sure that I do) big endian of the words are used, so that what I'm looking for is actually 2312(0908h). This makes the impression of being correct as it is found very early in every file i try.

So then over to the next step:

> 4, Read the Globals substream, loading the BoundSheet8 records and the SST into memory. For more details, see Globals.

I look for 133(8500h) and it's found shortly after BOF, good. But the problem lies in the two next steps:

> 5, From the BoundSheet8 record that corresponds to the substream you want to open, read the first 4 bytes, which contains the lbPlyPos FilePointer.
>   6, Go to the offset in the stream specified by the lbPlyPos FilePointer. This is the BOF record for the worksheet.

So the following 4 bytes is a pointer that points to a position in the file I should go to. But reading those bytes in any order gives me a number that is larger than the whole file. And also, this part confuses me: "This is the BOF record for the worksheet." Wasn't that what I found in an earlier step? Hmm...

Sorry for my rambling. And I hope I make sense and that someone would be willing to help me a little.

**Update:**
Okay, I've gotten a little further with this. It's quite confusing to me but it seems that each record is also read as "big endian", ie the last variable in the record is the one that is positioned earliest in the file. Though I don't know if it applies to values with variable length? So, looking at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd773237%28v=office.12%29.aspx), the values of variable length are listed as the last one in a record. But obviously they can't come as the first in the file because there would be no way to know how many bytes to read in if that info comes after it?
Anyway, if I ignore this value, and and skip 2 bytes for dt and A/unused and read the following 4 bytes as a uint it turns out as 1130 in my case. Adding that to the pos of the first BOF gives me the exact position of the sheet-BOF. And that cant be a coincidence, right?

Now the next problem arises. After that BOF-record the index-record is supposed to follow immediately. But no matter in what way I read in the bytes it still makes no sense...
Here's what it looks like:

> 09 08 10 00 00 06 10 00 BB 0D CC 07 00 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 02 0E
>   00 00 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 00 00 12 00 00 00 3E 02 12 00 B6 06 00 00
>   00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7D 00 0C 00 00 00 00 00 DD
>   06 0F 00 00 00 00 00 7D 00 0C 00 02 00 02 00 DD 06 0F 00 00 00 00 00
>   7D 00 0C 00 04 00 04 etc...

The first 2 bytes there being the BOF record 09 08, or 0809 swapped which is 2057 (which represents BOF) so the rest should be the [INDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd907627.aspx) but doesn't make sense... I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Comment: "it seems that each record is also read as "big endian", ie the last variable in the record is the one that is positioned earliest in the file" - This is not true. And you should be talking about location in the _stream_, not in the file.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the BOF record, I can tell you it refers to Begining Of File and is at the start of every sub-stream the excel file contains. Given that you usually have 3 worksheets, all worksheets have VBA code sheets and the workbook has a code sheet you are looking at 8 BOF records.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did figure the BOF-record might represent the beginning of file as well as each sheet. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

The BOF record is not just the first two bytes. The next two bytes "10 00" tell you the length of the rest of the record (this means 0x0010, or 16 bytes). However, after counting forward 16 bytes there is no Index record there. (From [the list of record ID's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd908813%28v=office.12%29.aspx), the ID of the Index record is supposed to be 523, which is 0x020b, which will appear as "0b 02".)

You must be looking at the wrong BOF. You must have either not found the lbPlyPos pointer or followed it incorrectly.

> So the following 4 bytes is a pointer that points to a position in the file I should go to. But reading those bytes in any order gives me a number that is larger than the whole file

Make sure you are skipping over the two bytes which give you the size of the record.